# php / mysql divide result displays as 6.2E-5

Tags: php, mysql

Have such mysql query `SELECT CurrencyRate/Units AS FinalCurrencyRate`

Value for `CurrencyRate` is `0.06200000` and value for `Units` is `1000`.

So `0.06200000` / `1000` and get `6.2E-5`

The same result if `echo $result = 0.06200000 / 1000 . '<br>';`

If `echo $result = number_format( (0.06200000 / 1000), 10, '.', '' ) . '<br>';` then can get `0.0000620000`

What is solution for mysql query to get normal number instead of `6.2E-5`?

Found `round(CurrencyRate/Units,10)`

But what if do not know number of `00000` after decimal? For example `0.06200000` / `1000000000000000000`

Comment: You're probably using `FLOAT` for your column type. You should change it to `DECIMAL`. Floating point is inexact because the exact numbers you're looking for can't always be represented in binary.

Comment: oh, me stupid. I used `varchar(150)`. will change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use type [DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html) for such values. This would make your values display the way you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are working with currencies, use [BC Math Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) for better percision. You can set the number of digits after the decimal place in the result when you use them. Example:

```
//bcdiv - it divides to numbers
echo bcdiv('105', '6.55957', 3);  // 16.007
```